# Replace a number with another number

Tags: regex

Consider a list of numbers:

```
1
2
3
17
8
9
23
...etc.
```

I want to replace these numbers with another number, based on another list:

```
1001=1
1002=2
1003=3
1004=8
1005=23
1006=9
1007=17
```

What is the quickest way to do this? (like using regular expression in Notepad++, etc.)

Comment: Why not just do a normal search and replace..

Comment: What would I search and replace?  There's hundreds of unique numbers...

Comment: A regular expression is almost certainly not the right way to go about this.  What form specifically is the list and mapping in?

Comment: The list is just a single number on a line by itself, I am not a programmer, so please don't tell me to go program something.

Comment: They are randomly assigned, is there a way to check the number for its equivalent value?

Comment: do the items in the list correspond (item 1 in one list = item 1 in the other?)  If so, then it seems like an easy operation to me.

Comment: As you might read from the faq, "Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it." So if you ask a question here, telling you to program something is expected and valid answer.

Comment: A regex will identify a single pattern and replace it with a single pattern. Where you want to do several hundred different replacements for several hundred different patterns, a single regex is not going to be what you want, unless there is a simple relationship between the input and output patterns that you can capture. Regex's ^ and $ could be used to make sure you match the _entire_ line if you do decide to do search/replaces, and that's about it. But if you're thinking about the _best_ way to do this, you're already a programmer, whether you know it or not.

Comment: Regex is code. A spreadsheet is probably the best tool, if you dont want to write code. Put your translation table in a worksheet, not sure what the function would be though, anyone else know that part?

Comment: Khilon, you are totally right, I'm sorry.

Comment: @Brian Maltzan is right, use a spreadsheet.  You need to have the replacement table sorted, then use VLOOKUP in Excel. Pass in the number you want and the table of replacements, it returns the new value. Copy and paste out of there.

Comment: @Lou Franco - this is the answer I was looking for, but I ended up learning a bit of Ruby and coded a solution.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3):

I do this kind of thing in perl -- something like

```
%replacements = (1=>1001, 2=>1002, 3=>1003 );
while (<>) {
   chomp;
   @nums = split(/ /);
   @outnums = ();
   foreach $n (@nums) {
       $outnums[$#outnums + 1] = $replacements{$n};
   }
   print join(' ', @outnums)."\n";
}
```

then run

```
perl scriptname.pl < infile > outfile
```

Comment: perl is very sexy indeed

Comment: awk - or any language with associative arrays - also does this easily.  In this example, since the keys are numeric, not arbitrary strings, you could even get away with dynamic but non-associative arrays.

Comment: Also, even better would be to read the replacements from a file (presumably an argument to the script).  It depends, perhaps, on how often this is going to have to be done.  Generating the mapping is the hard part, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Put your mappings into an array (or a dictionary, depending on how your numbers are, such that):

```
map[oldvalue] = newvalue;
```

Then iterate over the original list and replace, eg:

```
oldlist = '1\n2\n3\n17'
map = {'1' : '1001', '2': '1002', '3' : '1003', '17' : '1007'}

result = ''
for num in oldlist.split('\n'):
    result += map[num] + '\n'
```

See it on [ideone](http://ideone.com/bZoLl)

Answer (score 1):

You don't want a regex since you need to somehow map the numbers to their replacements. Here's a script in Ruby:

Given a file called 'nums' like so:

```
1
2
3
```

...and so on...

```
map = {
  1 => 1000,
  2 => 2000,
  ...etc...
}
results = File.open('output','a')
File.open('nums').readlines.each do |line|
  results.write( map[line.to_i].to_s + "\n" ) if map.has_key?(line.to_i)
end
```

Run this like: `ruby thescript.rb` and the file 'output' now has your new number set.